# Getting HadoopAccessorException while checking oozie workflow status

Tags: exception, hadoop, workflow, oozie

```
Workflow Name : map-reduce-wf
App Path      : hdfs://10.226.226.34:8020/user/user/examples/apps/map-reduce/workflow.xml
Status        : KILLED
Run           : 0
User          : user
Group         : users
Created       : 2013-01-23 11:25
Started       : 2013-01-23 11:25
Last Modified : 2013-01-23 11:26
Ended         : 2013-01-23 11:26
```

Actions

```
ID                                                                            Status    Ext ID                 Ext Status Err Code

0000002-130123162445627-oozie-oozi-W@mr-node                                  ERROR     -                      ERROR      HadoopAccessorException
```

Any1 came acroos this error.. Plz guide me.. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Check the oozie.log file on your oozie server to see if there is more information and post your findings back into your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had come across the same exception. It was to do with the user permissions. The user which you are using to run oozie, check its permissions.

Comment: user permissions for job.properties and workflow.xml file?

Comment: i am also facing same problem, status is showing "RUNNING" and not changing only.

Answer (score 2):

This might happen if you're using the wrong jobTracker port. By default oozie examples use port 8021 (MR1), but if you're using MR2/YARN you need to change it to 8032. This value is set in your job.properties file.

If you want to update all of the example jobs at once, from your examples directory run the following:

```
sed -i 's/8021/8032/g' examples/apps/*/*.*
```

Make sure to overwrite the example files in HDFS with the updates (you might even want to cat the job.properties file in HDFS to confirm it has been overwritten).